# A JavaScript language problem

Tags: javascript, scope

I got a JavaScript error when running codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    var fn = function () {
        //var aaa = 'AAA';
        return function () {
            alert(aaa);
        };
    }();

    var foo2 = function () {
        var aaa = 'BBB';
        (function () {
            alert(aaa); // 'BBB'
        })();
        fn(); // Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: aaa is not defined
    }();
</script>
```

I think when `fn` function running, it should be able to find `aaa` in `foo2` function.

But I got error. Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `aaa` is out of `fn()`'s scope. What may be confusing you is that

```
(function () {
  alert(aaa); // 'BBB'
})();
```

Is working but `fn()` isn't. What's happening is that since "BBB" is defined *and* invoked inside `foo2`, `alert(aaa)` and `aaa` are in the same scope, and it works just fine.

Given that, you have two options:

1. Declare `aaa` in a upper scope:

   ```
   var aaa = 'BBB';

   var fn = function () {
     return function () {
       alert(aaa);
     };
   };

   var foo2 = function () {
       (function () {
           alert(aaa); // 'BBB'
       })();
       fn();
   };
   ```
2. Pass `aaa` as a parameter to `fn()`:

   ```
   var fn = function (aaa) {
     return function () {
       alert(aaa);
     };
   };

   var foo2 = function () {
       var aaa = 'BBB';
       (function () {
           alert(aaa); // 'BBB'
       })();
       fn(aaa);
   };
   ```

Here's an article about javascript scoping:

http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> I think when fn function running, it should be able to find aaa in foo2 function.

No, it should not. `aaa` is declared in `foo2` as a local variable, it is not accessible inside `fn`. What makes you think otherwise? No programming language I have seen would behave like that.

It will work if you uncomment the line `//var aaa = 'AAA';` but then the alert inside `fn` will of course say "AAA" and not "BBB".

Answer (score 1):

You declared `var aaa` within `foo2`, so the scope of it is restricted to `foo2`. `fn` has no access to it.

Either declare `var aaa` outside of both functions, or pass it to `fn` as a parameter.